# Contents of FrameLayout are not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout

Due to margin and padding problems with the regular `Button` class I've been working on a custom `Layout` that extends `FrameLayout`.
I ran into a problem, that the contents of the layout do not get displayed.
As soon as I'm changing this to another e.g. `RelativeLayout` the contents get displayed.

This is my relevant code:

```
private static final int COLOR = R.styleable.MyButton_color;
private static final int TEXT = R.styleable.MyButton_text;

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  LayoutParams backgroundParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  backgroundParams.gravity = Gravity.FILL;
  background = new ImageView(context, null, defStyle);
  addView(background, backgroundParams);

  text = new TextView(context, null, defStyle);
  text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
  LayoutParams textParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  textParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
  addView(text, textParams);

  TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.MyButton);
  try {
    setColor(Color.values()[a.getInteger(COLOR, 0)]);
    setText(a.getString(TEXT));
  } finally {
    a.recycle();
  }
}

public void setText(CharSequence text) {
  this.text.setText(text);
}

private void setColor(Color color) {
  switch (color) {
    case ORANGE:
      text.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.text_blue));
      background.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_orange);
      break;
    case BLUE:
      //TODO set colors
      break;
  }
}
```

What am I missing on this one?

Comment: You may want to add those views with specific `LayoutParams`, more precisely `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: I'm using `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. They are in my imports, which I have not provided in the code example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite obvious.

```
LayoutParams backgroundParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

has to be replaced by

```
LayoutParams backgroundParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

The same applies for `textParams`, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Extending FrameLayout, this is a special layout which has set a flag on most API versions to not call draw functions.

To overcome this, set the flag to false when constructing:

```
public MyButton(
...
    setWillNotDraw(false);
...
```